# Android - How do I add an ImageView over a button contained within a Grid Layout

Tags: android

I am developing a bingo type android app and have a grid layout of buttons , i want to be able to add an "X" vector image over the text when the button is clicked, id rather the image appeared above the text as opposed to replacing it, any help would be greatly appreciated!

[desired effect](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcyIL.png)

Comment: Stack them using FrameLayout or RelativeLayout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could stack an ImageView with the "X" vector as its image on top of the button and change its visibility once the button is clicked using an OnClickListener. Here is a simple example:

Layout:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"/>

<ImageView
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv_cross"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_clear_24px"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/btn"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/btn"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@id/btn"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@id/btn"/>
```

Where "@drawable/ic_clear_24px" is the "X" vector.

Activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button btn = findViewById(R.id.btn);
    final ImageView iv_cross = findViewById(R.id.iv_cross);

    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            iv_cross.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
    });
}
```

Note that the visibility of the ImageView is set to invisible by default.

Comment: This is a good solution but i think i am being prevented by doing because all of my buttons are in a grid layout when i try to add an imageview over its added to the layout instead of staying where i want it, any solution for this (ideally without changing the layout) , thank you for your answer!